# Is there a way to run complex R workloads in a serverless manner in the cloud?

Tags: r, azure, serverless

We are currently manually running complex R workloads on a monster VM in the Azure Cloud. Some workloads consume all VM resources and create bottlenecks. Typically workloads take 30min - 3hrs

Is there a way to improve performance to run R workloads in a serverless and isolated manner, perhaps using containers or cloud functions  ?

We are also interested in investing in a tool that we could use to manage/administer/orchestrate workloads in a seamless end to end fashion.
Something like Azure Data Factory but for stitching together stuff in R.

Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any third party ( non Azure ) products would also be of interest to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to run R in Azure.  I would think HDInsights, Databricks or AML would be good for you to review.

[image]

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/r-developers-guide#azure-services-with-r-language-support)